# Is there a way to have a lambda reference inside a function always return the opposite bool value?

Tags: python, function, lambda

If I have a function that takes in a lambda reference as a parameter, and returns that reference so when it's called, it returns the value of that lambda function (boolean).

Is there a way to have it return the opposite boolean value?

```
def returns_diff(lambda_function):
    return lambda_function
f = returns_diff(lambda x : x > 2)
f(0) 
# I know I can do it this way but I want to do it inside the function.
# print(not(f(0)))
```

---> Should return `True` because it's supposed to return `False` since 0 is not bigger than two (return the opposite value of the lambda function)

**I know I can just do: `not(f(0))` when calling it, but I want to do it inside the function, not when I call it.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to generate a function that returns the boolean opposite of a given function, you can do it like this:

```
def returns_diff(func):
    return lambda x: not func(x)


f = returns_diff(lambda x: x>2)
f(0) # returns True
```

That's assuming the functions take one argument, as in your question. You can also make a version that works for functions with any number of positional or keyword arguments:

```
def returns_diff(func):
    return lambda *args, **kwargs: not func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can i use classes? Or it need to be just plain functions? With classes i would do

```
class diff:
def __init__(self,lambda_func):
    self.lambda_func = lambda_func
def __call__(self,x): 
    return  not(self.lambda_func(x)) 

f = diff(lambda x: x > 2)
f(0) #True
```